# Adding hello world to cpanel

Tags: html, cpanel

I've just signed up with host gator and created my own domain. I am trying to create my own website from scratch without using WordPress or trying to use it as less as possible. I have watched multiple tutorials and most of them are about using WordPress but that implements the code for you. As of now, I am just trying to test my HTML code using "hello world" through cPanel. I'm not sure what file I need to delete in order to start implementing my own code through cPanel. I've also downloaded FileZilla and connected the two but, I still can't see my "hello world" test. Please help with a detailed description of what I need to exactly do. Here is the code I am testing it on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <h1>This is hello world!</h1>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML file has no body tag. Thats a problem. As for cpanel, you probably need to copy your file to index.html and delete index.php if it exists. More information is required on your setup. This sounds more like a configuration issue than programming issue. Maybe try on a different stack exchange site?

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in to your cPanel account in your browser with the username and password provided by your Web hosting service.
2. Click the "File Manager" icon from the main page. If prompted, select "web root" as your desired location, because this is where you need to place files to make them available online.
3. Click the "New File" icon to create a new file. Create the front page on your site. This file should be named "index" or "default." For example, your host will recognize "index.php" as the front page or "default.html."